# Intersecting $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisors on a singular variety (Cone)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $S\subset \mathbf{P}^2$ be a quadric, and let $X \subset \mathbf A^3$ be the cone over $S$ with vertex $P$.

As a practice, I want to calculate $$(K_X+L)|_L,$$ where $L$ is a rule of $X$. My progress is as follows:

Let $\pi : \widetilde X \rightarrow X$ be a resolution of $P\in X$

First note that

1. these are $\mathbf Q$-Cartier divisors, so the expression makes 
   sense ($K_X$ is Cartier, and so is $2L$);
2. $\pi_* \pi^* D = D, D \in \text{Pic}X$;
3. $K_{\widetilde X} = \pi^*K_X + E, E$ the exceptional divisor;
4. $\pi^*D.E=0, D\in \text{Pic}X.$

We then go ahead and calculate

\begin{align}
(K_X+L)|_L &= \frac{1}{4}\pi_*\pi^*((2K_X+2L).(2L))\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\pi_*(\pi^*(2K_X+2L).\pi^*(2L)) \tag{1}\\
&= \pi_*((\pi^*K_X + \pi^*L).\pi^*L) \\
&= \pi_*((K_\widetilde X - E + \widetilde L + \frac{1}{2}E).\widetilde L) &(L^2=\frac{1}{2}P)\\
&= \pi_*(K_\widetilde L - \frac{1}{2}Q) &(Q \in \pi^{-1}P) \\
&= K_L - \frac{1}{2}P.
\end{align}

A different approach, which does not use (1), would be $L^2=\frac{1}{2}P$ and $\pi_*K_Y=K_X$, so

\begin{align}
K_X.L &= \frac{1}{2}\pi_*K_Y.2L \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\pi_*(K_Y.2\pi^*L) &\text{(using projection formula instead)}\\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\pi_*(K_Y.2\widetilde L + K_Y.E) &(\widetilde L^2 =0)\\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\pi_*(2K_\widetilde L - 2Q) & (\text{since }0=\pi^*K_X, E^2 = -2Q,Q\in E) \\
 &= K_L - P,
\end{align}
which leads to the same result.

Now, I am told the result is actually $K_L + \frac{1}{2}P$. Did I go wrong somewhere, or is this information incorrect?

Thanks.